# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Could not load : column "" of relation "" does not exist

Tags: django

I just added a field to my model and added the values of the field to my fixtures. However, I am getting this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture 'app/fixtures/tool.json': Could not load "": column "new_field" of relation "app_model" does not exist

which is the same error I got before even putting values in the fixture. What is it that I'm forgetting?

Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 64, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 104, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 167, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 201, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 889, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 939, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 654, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/webapps/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/webapps/my_app/tools/fixtures/tools.json': Could not load myapp.model(pk=3): column "new_field" of relation "myapp_model" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._LOCK,android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED', "new_field"...
```

Comment: In the dB the column does not exists for which a value is there in the fixture. You should migrate or double check that there are same attributes in fixture and dB table

Comment: Since I get this error, it won't let me migrate. Should I simply add this column to the db? @ArpitSolanki

Comment: Yeah that could be an option

Comment: you have any forms for this model ? or if you can show the full traceback it will be beneficial.

Comment: @Aniket I added the Traceback

Comment: You are using any method or third party tool named fixtures/tools.json ?

Comment: @Aniket yep, that's my fixtures json file

Comment: Just for temporary purpose disable it and migrate the model.

Comment: I tried taking it out of everything except for my models.py but I still get this error. I also just added the column to my table manually but still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150227/discussion-between-aniket-and-lexasaurus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way I solved this issue does not make so much sense. I did it by manually adding the column to the table. Then I ran `migrate`. Since I had the column the second time I was migrating, the error changed to column already exists. So then I deleted the column and it created the column automatically. I am not sure why it did not work in the first place, but if you have this problem, tweak around with the database.

Comment: I had the same problem, I ran python manage.py makemigrations and migrate but got this error. Turns out my app migrations didn't apply as they had been manually deleted before, so I had to recreate an empty database and run python manage.py makemigrations myapp for each app to get it working.